# javascript trying to send data from row in table using onclick to another page

Tags: javascript, html

Im triyng to send data from row in a table when i click on a button to another page

So when i click on the button i want the data from that row to be send to another page

in that page i want that the row that i have selected appears

```
function catalogo() {
//debugging para ver se foi pedido com sucesso
console.log(' pedido get  entrou success');
//create table to hold results
var txt = "";
txt += "<div class='table-responsive'>";
txt += "<table id='tblLivrosCatalogo' class='table table-sm'>";
txt += "<thead color:white '>";
txt += "<tr> <th>#ID</th> <th>Titulo</th> <th>Autor</th> <th>Género</th><th>Ano De Lançamento</th><th>Proprietário</th><th>Disponibilidade</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
//percorrer a variável data e por cada row cria a linha da tabela com os dados presentes
for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
    if (lista[i].disp_req == "Disponivel") {
        // console.log(i)
        //aqui os id's são os do mysql
        txt += "<tr><td>" + lista[i].id_livro + "</td><td>" + lista[i].titulo +
            "</td><td>" + lista[i].autor + "</td><td>" + lista[i].genero + "</td><td>" + lista[i].ano_lanc + "</td><td>" + lista[i].user_prop + "</td><td>" + lista[i].disp_req + "</td><td>" + "<a><i onclick ='clickk()' id='icon' class='fas fa-book' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Requisitar Livro'></i></a>" + "</tr>"
    }
    else {
        //aqui os id's são os do mysql
        txt += "<tr><td>" + lista[i].id_livro + "</td><td>" + lista[i].titulo +
            "</td><td>" + lista[i].autor + "</td><td>" + lista[i].genero + "</td><td>" + lista[i].ano_lanc + "</td><td>" + lista[i].user_prop + "</td><td>" + lista[i].disp_req + "</td></tr>"
    }
}
txt += "</tbody></table></div>";
// send the table constructed for the view and show the result ( txt) in the object with ID result
$("#tablecatalogo").html(txt);
```

}

Note: this table is generated by mysql when i register a book it goes to mysql and then display in here

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery you can do it this way by simply adding a function:

```
function clickk(element) {
  var rowData = $(this).parent().children("td").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
  // pass to another page
  window.location = '/page.html?params=' + JSON.stringify(rowData);
}
```

Your HTML

```
...
<a onclick='clickk(this)'><i id='icon' class='fas fa-book' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Requisitar Livro'></i></a>
...
```

Now you will receive the parameters by `GET` method.

Comment: im using nodejs so in the window.location i need to put the root of the page i want.  is  possible to send just the values from the row of the table by clicking in the button right?  its bad i cant print my html pages to here ...